# Why does this code print 10 even when class Car is not instantiated in Python 2

Tags: python-2.7

```
a = 10

class Car():
  global a
  print a
```

When I run this code, the value `10` gets printed. Why?

Comment: Because class body is evaluated on type declaration, not class instance initialization.

Answer (score 0):

When running a Python program, everything is executed, with the exception of functions.  Try putting the code in class Car into a function.